# Adding user to Active Directory Group .net core: A referral was returned from the server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm building a .net core 3 website where I'm trying to add a user to an Active Directory security group. The below code works fine in my development environment but once it's deployed to IIS I receive:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007202B):
>   A referral was returned from the server.

The error occurs at "group.Save();"

```
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ad.xxx.com:389", 
    "DC=ad,DC=xxx,DC=com", svcAccountUsername, svcAccountPw))
    {
       GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);
       group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
       group.Save();
    }
```

Again, this works locally in my development environment but not once deployed to IIS. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking up the account that you are trying to add to the AD. Other things i can suggest is using the debugger to confirm the account / group exists in the domain that you are running this under.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain" ...))
    {
       GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);
       // Do some validation / logging to make sure there is a group returned.

       var principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
       // Do some validation here to make sure principal is not null

       group.Members.Add(principal);
       group.Save();
    }
```

Make sure the server running this script has access to the domain you are updating.

Answer (score 0):

A referral means that you aren't talking to the right server, but the server knows who you should be talking to. If you look into the exception object more, you might even find which server it wants to send you to.

This can happen if the group is not on the same domain that you passed to the `PrincipalContext`.